# Combining many polygons from multiple datasets into one raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, rasterization

I am a beginner in ArcGIS. I have a query regarding merging many polygons to form one big polygon, and then rasterizing it. The polygons are from varied datasets and represent different environmentally protected areas, and I want to make them into one raster.

Comment: I tried the merge command But I get this error 'Could not write value 'Central' to output field AREA failed to execute (Merge)

Comment: Is that error happening with all the polygons, or just some? Can you edit one of the polygons and copy the others into that feature class?

Comment: This is happening when length of the same name field is shorter in upper layer. Check field AREA length in your inputs and arrange them accordingly in MERGE window, i.e.  longest to be at the top. I hope fields are of same type, e.g. AREA is text everywhere

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a two step process...

1. Use **[Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000)** to combine all your polygons into one polygon (tool found in the Data Management / General toolbox)
2. Use **[Feature to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Feature_to_Raster/00120000002v000000/)** to change the polygon into a raster (tool found in the Conversion / To Raster toolbox).

These are both straightforward tools. The most complicated part with Feature to Raster is figuring out what cell size you should use (balancing accuracy and spatial resolution against the file size of the resulting raster).